# Create template function to call other functions with that functions parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I want to create a function like `thread()` function (get N parameters). I think I have to use a template like this:

```
template <typename Func, typename Param1, ...>
void function(params)
{

}
```

But for my function, I have to set a limited number of parameters. In the `thread()` function you can give this function N parameters. How is it possible to create a function and give the parameters same inside function params?

```
template <typename Func, typename Param1, typename Param2, typename Param3 = typename()>
    void Remote_function_caller(Func Function_name, Param1 P1, Param2 P2, Param3 P3 = Param3())
{
Function_name(P1, P2, P3);
}

void Tool1(int Data1, int Data2)
{

}

void Tool2(int Data1, int Data2, int Data3)
{

}

void main()
{
      // Call tool 1
      Remote_function_caller(Tool1, 5, 6);

      // Call tool 2
      Remote_function_caller(Tool2, 5, 6, 9);
}
```

To call `Tool1` I have to enter 2 parameters but system gives an error because caller needs 3 parameters (and load that function with 3 parameters)...

Comment: Look into variadic templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using *variadic templates*:

```
template<typename Func, typename... Params>
void function_caller(Func func, Params&&... params) {
    func(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
}
```

Short example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename Func, typename... Params>
void function_caller(Func func, Params&&... params) {
    func(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
}

void foo(int x, int y) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

void bar(int x, int y, int z) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    function_caller(foo, 5, 6);
    function_caller(bar, 5, 6, 9);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
void foo(int, int)
void bar(int, int, int)
```

Comment: what is (typename... Params)??? (what is (...))? means every param ? system detect it as every param?

Comment: @Elh48 It's all about variadic templates. Here is a good starting point: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/